# Eclipse Indigo Release on Ubuntu 11.04 - (Natty Narwhal) using client JVM

Tags: eclipse-indigo

Configuration details:

IDE: Eclipse Indigo Java EE IDE for Web Developers.
  OS: Ubuntu Linux 11.04
Java: java version "1.6.0_30"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_30-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 20.5-b03, mixed mode)

When I use jconsole to check the JVM details of eclipse process, it shows that its using client JVM and JIT. I tried following:

in eclipse.ini:

-vmargs
...
-server

but it doesn't work.

Please help. thanks in advance.

Comment: forgot to mention that my machine has 32 bit OS and 4 GB of RAM.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly check the command line via "ps -eaf|grep -i Catalina" which will show you something like this:

```
adahar    5933  5552  0 Aug28 ?        00:11:45 /opt/jdk1.5.0_22/bin/java
-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,suspend=y,address=localhost:53946 
-Dcatalina.base=/home/adahar/workspace-indigo/.metadata/.plugins
```

/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp2 -Dcatalina.home=/home/adahar/soa/model-eclipse 
    -Dwtp.deploy=/home/adahar/workspace-indigo/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp2/wtpwebapps 
    -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/home/adahar/soa/model-eclipse/endorsed -Xmx2g -XX:MaxPermSize=192m 
    -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath /home/adahar/soa/model-eclipse/bin/bootstrap.jar:
    /opt/jdk1.5.0_22/lib/tools.jar org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap start

There you can see the options if they were successfully put on the command line.

If it's still not working, then it's a java issue. My guess would be that Eclipse is not a server application, i.e. it's got a GUI, so java is defaulting to client mode.